# c++ loop runs forever without waiting for input

Tags: c++, loops, cin

I am trying to write code that will loop and input user input to a class and print out a chart. This is my main method:

```
int main()
{
    Company productMatrix;
    int inputNumber = 0;
    cout << "enter the salesman id or -1 to quit." << endl;
    cin >> inputNumber;
    while(inputNumber != -1)
    {
        int salesman = inputNumber;
        cout << "enter the product id." << endl;
        cin >> inputNumber;
        int product = inputNumber;
         cout << "enter the amount sold." << endl;
        cin >> inputNumber;
        double dollarValue = inputNumber;
        productMatrix.inputSales(salesman, product, dollarValue);
        cout << "enter the salesman id or -1 to quit." << endl;
        cin >> inputNumber;
    }
    productMatrix.printChart();
    cout << "Goodbye!";
    return 0;
}
```

when I run the program, it will let me input one set of data and then loop forever without waiting for me to stop. This is what it looks like:

```
enter the salesman id or -1 to quit.
3
enter the product id.
2
enter the amount sold.
55.99
enter the salesman id or -1 to quit.
enter the product id.
enter the amount sold.
enter the salesman id or -1 to quit.
enter the product id.
enter the amount sold.
// etc...
```

I'm guessing there is something wrong with my loop. How can I fox this?

Comment: double dollarValue = inputNumber;

inputNumber is a integer type and dollar value is a float. So there is a type mismatch. You can create another variable like dollarInput and store the dollar value there.

Answer (score 2):

You're writing a double `55.99` to an integer, so `cin` takes 55 and it has `'.'` in the buffer which is always `!=-1` but never gets read into as integer.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with following line.

```
double dollarValue = inputNumber;
```

inputNumber is a integer type and dollar value is a float. So there is a type mismatch. You can create another variable like dollarInput and store the dollar value there

Answer (score 0):

`inputNumber` is an `int`.  But you entered a value (55.99) that can not be interpreted as an `int`. This put `cin` into an error state. Until the error is cleared, all future operations with `cin` fail. So it doesn't wait for your input, and the variables retain their values, and you can never get that `-1` that the loop needs to terminate.

To check for an error, just use a plain old if statement:

```
if (cin) {
    // cin is okay
}
else {
    // cin is not okay
}
```

You can also be a little more concise and put your input operation directly in an `if` statment:

```
if (cin >> inputNumber) {
```

To clear the error:

```
cin.clear();
```

You will also probably need to clear the input stream, otherwise the erroneous input will remain in the input buffer, and `cin` will just try to read it again:

```
cin.ignore(); // discard one character from the input buffer
// or
cin.ignore(N); // discard N characters from the input buffer
```

Anyway, that's the cause of the infinite loop.  But if you had just input directly into a `double`, instead of an `int`, you wouldn't have seen this issue.  Isn't that what you want anyway?

Answer (score 0):

To add to prajmus's answer, you can see the additional 'junk' in the input stream by adding the following 'cin' read:

```
...
double dollarValue = inputNumber;
productMatrix.inputSales(salesman, product, dollarValue);
cout << "enter the salesman id or -1 to quit." << endl;

double myDbl;
cin >> myDbl;
cout << "read the following double:" << myDbl << endl;
...
```

The added "cin >> myDbl" will read the '.99' from the input stream and the added cout will yield:

```
0.99
```